# Installing Informix on Ubuntu

Tags: database, ubuntu, installation, informix

Can someone please suggest whether I can install informix database on ubuntu.

My version of Ubuntu is 11.10

Is it freely available.

If yes please suggest me some friendly installation guide or link.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can install Informix on many Linux distributions including Ubuntu.

You must have IBM ID (freely available) to download Developer Version of Informix from http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/informix/downloads.html. Then you must select if your server is 32 bit or 64 bit version of Linux. After downloading appropriate tar file you must untar it, read documentation (README.html), prepare environment as it is described in it and run installer. In README.html there is quick install instruction which I found friendly :-)